Filter the docker ps output with a Bash alias
I'm using Docker for many of our services and the command docker ps is essential for me but I hate the long and extensive output.
For example in this server:
[root@server docker-postgres]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE              COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                 PORTS     NAMES
020ec906a5ed   bitnami/pgpool:4   "/opt/bitnami/script…"   2 weeks ago   Up 2 weeks (healthy)             pgpool
d40dd0f76e19   postgres_img       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 weeks ago   Up 19 hours                      postgres

The only things that I look when run docker ps are these:
pgpool        Up   2  weeks  (healthy)
postgres      Up  19  hours  

I'm able to get that output running this command:
docker ps | awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' '{print $6,$5}' | column -t --table-right 2,3,4

But that command is very large and I tried to set an alias just like this:
alias dps="docker ps | awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' '{print $6,$5}' | column -t --table-right 2,3,4"

But running the alias I get this result:
[root@server docker-postgres]# dps
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,}
awk: cmd. line:1:        ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,}
awk: cmd. line:1:         ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {print ,}
awk: cmd. line:1:          ^ unexpected newline or end of string

I don't know what is happening, I have tried changing several things in the alias line but no success...

man docker-container-ls says The formatting option (--format) pretty-prints container output, so using --format "table {{.Names}}\t{{.Status}}" (or similar) could be an option (untested).

That gives me the desired output. Also, it works well adding it to an alias
alias dps="docker container ls --format 'table {{.Names}}\t{{.Status}}'"
Thank you!

Do not use alias.  Since 1996, the bash documentation has stated "For almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."  I am quite sure that even in 1996, 'almost every purpose' was only there out of an excess of caution.  Just stop using alaises!  Functions give you more flexibility and are more robust.

@WilliamPursell There is one extremely good reason to use aliases from your shell: the ability to cancel them and run the original command with only a single character \foo.  With functions you need to type in 8 characters to override them command foo.  I use hundreds of custom functions in my shell using custom names, then use an alias of the name I wanted to refer to the custom function name.  Then I can override my function with just a \foo. Example: function cdls { cd "$1" && ls; }; alias cd='cdls'

The reason your alias is failing is the incorrect quoting. You can nominally fix it by backslash-escaping any dollar signs (or double quotes, or backticks) in the alias definition:
alias dps="docker ps | awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' '{print \$6,\$5}' | column -t --table-right 2,3,4"

But aliases suck anyway. Use a function instead.
dps () {
    docker ps "$@" |
    awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' '{print $6,$5}' |
    column -t --table-right 2,3,4
}

Of course, in this particular case, using the --format option of docker ps or docker container ls is vastly superior, like you already discovered.
dps() {
    docker container ls --format 'table {{.Names}}\t{{.Status}}' "$@"
}

Perhaps notice also the "$@" at the end which allows you to pass in additional options or arguments.

With your Awk command, I get the PORTS and STATUS fields rather than the ones you requested, so there's probably more to debug there if you really want to fix it.

Thanks to the suggestion of @pmf this is what I was looking for:
alias dps="docker container ls --format 'table {{.Names}}\t{{.Status}}'"

it gives me this result:
NAMES      STATUS
pgpool     Up 2 weeks (healthy)
postgres   Up 19 hours


You apparently missed the vastly more important and repeated suggestions in the comments and answers ("Do not use alias", "Don't use an alias; use a function.", "aliases suck anyway. Use a function instead.",  etc.). So, use a function, not an alias, e.g. dps() { docker container ls --format 'table {{.Names}}\t{{.Status}}'; }

@EdMorton But why?  They were just asking how to fix their alias line, and they got it working using this docker container command.  It no longer uses awk or any Bash $variables, so there's really nothing remotely dangerous about using an alias now.

@Raven think of it the other way - functions can be used for more and in more contexts and behave more intuitively than aliases and are no harder to write than aliases so why use an alias rather than a function? Choosing to use an alias rather than a function is like choosing to not quote a variable - sometimes you can get away with it but there's just no reason to do it and if you do then you often end up having to change your code later to make the better choice.

What do you mean not harder to write?  alias foo='bar'; is a lot shorter and simpler than function foo { bar; }.  16 vs. 21 characters, and the function has uglier syntax.

@Raven You shouldn't use the function keyword as it does nothing but make your code non-portable. Just write foo() {bar;} instead - that's 12 vs 16 characters if that matters to you. Uglier is in the eye of the beholder but FWIW I disagree with you.

I care about clear code, and the word function is extremely clear and helpful to have in the code.  It's something you can search for, e.g. /^fun in Vim.  I use this to generate a list of functions at the top of my code.  I dislike having foo() { ...; } instead of function foo { ...; } because it is logically invalid -- functions in Bash don't support (), variables can't be placed in () to pass them into the function, as works in nearly every other programming language with functions.  This makes it seem like it is something it is not.  This is a Docker/Bash question, not POSIX sh.

@Raven sounds like you have your own ideas of how best to use bash that are contrary to the common advice given by experts who've been using bash and other shells for decades (e.g. you define aliases frequently and use the "function" keyword - you can google both for more opinions on why not to do either thing if you care, I'm not here to convince anyone). I understand you have reasons for what you do. IMO the reasons NOT to do what you do are far greater but, of course, it's your code so your decision.

@Raven by the way, unless it's under one of my answers, if you don't tag me in a comment then I probably won't see it as the site won't notify me of it. It was just pure chance that I came across your most recent comment to me above.

Don't use an alias; use a function.
dps () {
  docker ps | awk -F '[[:space:]][[:space:]]+' '{print $6,$5}' | column -t --table-right 2,3,4
}

The immediate problem is that $6 and $5 were being expanded immediately at alias-definition time, because you used double-quotes for the alias definition. Nothing inside the definition of the function is subject to shell evaluation until the function is called.
Of course, the fact that docker ls is capable of producing the output you want without having to parse the output of docker ps means you should use that instead of this pipeline.
